# some mongoose fields not inserted into database

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, authorization, mongoose-schema

The code below is in the usermodel but when i add a new field like role and post it using postman, the role is not inserted in the database. i don't know where i went wrong

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A user must have a name']
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide your email'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email']
  },
  photo: {
    type: String
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'guide', 'lead-guide', 'admin']
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide a password'],
    minlength: 8,
    select: false
  },
  passwordConfirm: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please confirm the password'],
    validate: {
      //works only on create and save
      validator: function(el) {
        return el === this.password;
      },
      message: 'Passwords are not the same'
    },
    message: 'Passwords are not the same!'
  },
  passwordChangedAt: Date
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  // Only run th
```

type here

```
is function if password was actually modified
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  // Hash the password with the cost of 12
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);

  //Delete the passwordConfirm field
  this.pas`your text`swordConfirm = undefined;
  next();
});

userSchema.methods.correctPassword = async function(
  candidatePassword,
  userPassword
) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, userPassword);
};

userSchema.methods.changedPasswordAfter = function(JWTTimestamp) {
  if (this.passwordChangedAt) {
    const changedTimestamp = parseInt(
      this.passwordChangedAt.getTime() / 100,
      10
    );
    return JWTTimestamp < changedTimestamp;
  }
  //false means not changed
  return false;
};
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

in that above code the role field when i assign it in postman. it is not showing up but the data get saved to the database though the role field still in the database is missing

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Budsr.png)

When i post the role field is missing

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, you need to remove the backtick character from the line where you delete the `passwordConfirm` field. Here's the corrected code:

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  // Only run this function if password was actually modified
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  // Hash the password with the cost of 12
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);

  // Delete the passwordConfirm field
  this.passwordConfirm = undefined;

  next();
});
```

After making this change, the role field should be saved properly in the database when you send a POST request with Postman.